# Mapping Sharepoint Drive Woes

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am hoping some scripting whiz can help me out.  We recently moved to Office 365 and I am using the SharePoint libraries as a replacement for their traditional file server.  Most users don't like web browsing to open their files (too many extra clicks) and I have figured out how to map the SharePoint drive.  Problem is the mapped drive will work at best for 5 days before you have to go back into the SharePoint library and click on the Open With Explorer to revive the mapped drive.

Has anybody figured a way to keep that map drive more persistent?  I have found scripts but most of them are old and must work with previous editions of SharePoint online.

The closest one I have found so far is at
http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/7728.aspx?pi14176=2

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can script the authentication with Internet Explorer using PowerShell. There is a PowerShell script you can use here http://www.lieben.nu/numb3rs/?page_id=129 and then customise so suit your needs.

The PowerShell/scripting approach does rely on automating Internet Explorer to create the cookies which can be unreliable at times. If you would consider a commercial solution for drive mapping then take a look at Zee Drive which authenticates to SharePoint Online directly, maps the drives permanently and does a whole lot more such as local caching: http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/

Disclosure: Zee Drive is a tool my company develops

Comment: McGeeky's lieben.nu page is now invalid.  But there is another powershell script at codeplex (if it is still up when you read this): http://office365drivemap.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=office365drivemap

Comment: Ah, and there is another powershell script here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/OneDriveMapper-automaticall-d7d498b0